# Using Google Sheets as a BigQuery data source with Repeated Fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use Google Sheets as a data source for a BigQuery table.
One of my data sets includes repeated fields.  How should the data be structured in GoogleSheets in order to work properly as a repeated field?

So far, I have tried separating the repeated values with a comma.
I do not get an error on table creation, but when I attempt to query the data, the error returned is 'internal error'.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to save repeated fields in Google Sheets as you can see [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_nested_and_repeated_data) (only files that support object-like schemes could support repeated fields).

If you must use a Google Spreadsheet, I think you can still workaround this issue with some extra processing.

I just created this file as an example in my Google Drive:

[image]

And loaded it in a table called "test4" having its type as STRING:

[image]

And now it's possible to work with this STRING and have the repeated fields you desire. One possibility is this query that makes use of [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#json_extract) function:

```
SELECT
  SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(user, '$.a'), r'\[|\]', ''), ',') a
FROM `your_table`
```

Which results in a repeated field again:

[image]